# Laravel Eloquent : Whereor array with joins

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Okay I have these three tables

```
users table:
id(int), name(varchar(20)), password(varchar(64)), created_at, updated_at

friends table:
id(int), targetID(int), ownerID(int), created_at, updated_at

posts table:
id(int), content(varchar(255)), ownerID(int), created_at, updated_at
```

I want to query posts made by the user himself and also his friends.

In this scenario, userid is 1 which is John

```
Users table data
1, John, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx
2, Mary, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx
3, Micheal, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx
4, Rick, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx
5, Sarah, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx

Friends table data
1, 2, 1, xxxx, xxxx
1, 3, 1, xxxx, xxxx
1, 4, 1, xxxx, xxxx

Posts table data
1, "Hi everyone", 1, xxxx, xxxx
2, "Good Morning", 1, xxxx, xxxx
3, "Welcome to our site", 2, xxxx, xxxx
4, "Quite a few members", 3, xxxx, xxxx
5, "haha", 5, xxxx, xxxx
```

As you can see from above scenario, our user, John is friends with id 2,3,4 which is Mary, Micheal and Rick.

I want to query the results out to show posts made by John and his friends order by created_at ascending. Of course, there will be inner join with users table to get the user's name based on the id.

I'm not sure on how Eloquent nested queries works as i expect it will have whereor ownerid= multiple users since a user have many friends who can make posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its okay i found the answer, here it is for future referencers.

```
$posts = Post::where('ownerID', function($query){
                    $query->select('targetID')
                        ->from(with(new Friends)->getTable())
                        ->where('ownerID', Auth::user()->id);
                })
                ->orWhere('ownerID', Auth::user()->id)
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.ownerID')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get(array('posts.id', 'posts.content', 'users.name', 'posts.created_at'));
```